# Python, не знаю как заменить нормально строку, голосовой ассистент

Tags: python, замена

Помогите, вот код:

```
for i in openfile:
    if i in task:
        apper = task.replace(i, '')
        apper = apper.strip()
        task = 'открыть'

if task == 'открыть':
    if apper == 'калькулятор':
            apper = task.replace('калькулятор', 'calc')
            os.system(f'{apper}.exe')
```

Comment: Для чего вам заменять строку? Почему вы не можете просто открыть калькулятор без замен?

Comment: голосовой ассистент, когда я говорю слово он должен это слово делать, в данном случае я говорю открыть калькулятор, а это русское слово, и он ничего не открывает !

Comment: "�����.exe" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.